# Sticking table rows and header in overflow table

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Currently I'm trying to build a table with a lot of data where I'm trying to stick the thead and TD on vertical and horizontal scroll. The table will have horizontal scroll so overflow auto.

I've built a quick sample here 
https://jsfiddle.net/4tmn5hdL/

```
.headerTitle{
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  left:0;
}
```

In the example I got the horizontal scroll to work but i'm trying to get the team name and the header to stick on vertical scroll.

Ideally I would like to use CSS but with overflow auto i cant seem to get it to work, any recommendations? Javascript solutions would be good as well.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you!!

Comment: the div should the scrolling element set to height:100vh , then , add vertical coordonates and avoid element to be full height or full width if you want to stick them. it will stick to its parent, until the parent moves or another sticky element comes in the area. https://jsfiddle.net/536p9hkt/

Comment: Thanks but the issue is that I don't want to have a predefined height and have another vertical scroll. The issue is in order to create horizontal scroll I need to add overflow and that removes the relationship with the parent for sticky.

Comment: unfortunately, the sticked element will scroll with its parent, not the window like a fixed element does. for this, sticky won't be of any help, it requires javascript.

Comment: Yeah that's what i was afraid of, thank you for replying back to my post.